# Group and Sort by multiple fields in lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

Supposing this array:

```
[
    { department: "D1", section: "S1", name: "Test", other: "value", hierarchy: 1 },
    { department: "D2", section: "S1", name: "Test", other: "value", hierarchy: 1 },
    { department: "D2", section: "S2", name: "Test", other: "value", hierarchy: 2 }
]
```

I want to group data by department, section and sort department, section, hierarchy

Result would be:

```
[
  "D1": [
     "S1": [
       { name: "Test", other: "value" }
     ]
  ],
  "D2": [
     "S1" [
       { name: "Test", other: "value" }
     ],
     "S2" [
       { name: "Test", other: "value" },
       { name: "Test", other: "value" }
     ]
  ]
]
```

Here's a skeleton of what direction I was heading:

```
var grouped = _.mapValues(_.chain(data).sortBy(item => item.hierarchy).groupBy(item => item.department).value(),
                      clist => clist.map(data => _.omit(data, 'department')));

_.forEach(grouped, function (item, department) {
    const members = _.groupBy(item, (item) => {
         return [item['section'], item['name']];
    });
});
```

Is there a better way to achieve it using Lodash?

Comment: Your result isn't valid javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using [_.groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy), then [_.mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapValues).

The groupBy call will group by department, then we use mapValues to group each department by section using groupBy again.

```js
const arr = [
    { department: "D1", section: "S1", name: "Test", other: "value", hierarchy: 1 },
    { department: "D2", section: "S2", name: "Test", other: "value", hierarchy: 2 },
    { department: "D2", section: "S1", name: "Test", other: "value", hierarchy: 1 },
    { department: "D2", section: "S2", name: "Test", other: "value", hierarchy: 2 }
]
const result = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(arr, 'department'), (v,k) => _.groupBy(v, 'section'));

console.log('Result:', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a `sort()` and `reduce()` in vanilla javascript.

```js
const
  input = [
    { department: "D2", section: "S1", name: "Test-d2-s1-h1", other: "value", hierarchy: 1 },
    { department: "D2", section: "S2", name: "Test-d2-s2-h2", other: "value", hierarchy: 2 },
    { department: "D1", section: "S1", name: "Test-d1-s1-h1", other: "value", hierarchy: 1 },
    { department: "D2", section: "S2", name: "Test-d2-s2-h1", other: "value", hierarchy: 1 },
  ],

  result = input
    .sort((a, b) =>
      a.department.localeCompare(b.department)
      || a.section.localeCompare(b.section)
      || a.hierarchy - b.hierarchy)
    .reduce((a, { department, section, hierarchy, ...data }) => (
      ((a[department] ??= {})[section] ??= []).push(data), a
    ), {});

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```